# How do I display the custom user meta fields I created in Gravity Forms User Registration?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin, user-registration

So I am using Gravity Forms User Registration and I am using a form that uses their custom user meta fields options. I created three custom ones under the user registration feed settings, all with three different names. I set each one to their respective fields that I have chosen. My problem is, I am trying to print out/echo the contents of each user meta fields just to verify that they indeed are storing and creating them. However, I seem to be having an issue. This is my code that spits out everything that's stored in the current user:

```
<?php
      $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user_id );
      print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
?>
```

This, by my understanding, spits out all the meta values associated with the user. It shows me the first_name, last_name metas, and more. However, it does not seem to show the new custom metas I created with the gravity form. Can someone please help me or direct me as to how I would access the custom metas I created and their values? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the current user actually has a value in those fields? IF they don't, that's one reason you wouldn't see them in your output.

You could peruse your database for those values, to be sure they exist. I had a problem where the values weren't being written to the database because of a plugin conflict.

Another test is to try a more specific display of a custom meta value - for example:

```
<?php echo esc_attr( the_author_meta( 'your-custom-meta-key', $user->ID ) ); ?>
```